# Python Printing Alternative

Tags: python, jupyter, cellular-automata

I'm using Python in Jupyter to write Cellular Automata, and in the end I'm basically plotting a huge (such as 100*100) array/list. The problem is that the array can't be plotted as a square in Jupyter since each row is splitted due to the large size of the matrix, and is there any way (saving as certain format?) to review the full matrix without distorting the shape? I tried Sublime but its printing interface is also too small.
[image]

Comment: Oh I just realised I could simply use Imshow or Matshow in Matplotlib module...

Answer (score 0):

You can save your array like this:

```
array = numpy.random.randint(2, size=(100,100))
numpy.savetxt('array.csv', array, delimiter=';', fmt='%1d')
```

This saves your array to a file called array.csv which you can open with any editor or office suite.